React-Native 0.74.1 build failed (error code '65') on macOS for iOS with rsync failed: Operation not permitted
React-Native 0.74.1 build failed (error code '65') on macOS for iOS with rsync failed: Operation not permitted
I keep getting issues after updating to the last version. I did a clean install but still bugging around the same type of issues.
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ Pods\ Resources /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-gjgvukaziwmwylavizreawanchja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.build/Script-ADC9DDC32298B72B3CF5DC8E.sh (in target 'qualityloop' from project 'qualityloop')
(1 failure)

I checked the details and whether I run "npx react-native run-ios" or "sudo npx react-native run-ios", the process stop at some point for an failed step in a script.
error: Sandbox: bash(7541) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/fs/Documents/DATA/dev_react-native/current/xxx/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-xxx.txt (in target 'xxx' from project 'xxx')
/Users/fs/Documents/DATA/dev_react-native/current/xxx/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-xxx/Pods-xxx-resources.sh: line 20: /Users/fs/Documents/DATA/dev_react-native/current/xxx/ios/Pods/resources-to-copy-xxx.txt: Operation not permitted

The line 20 :
RESOURCES_TO_COPY=${PODS_ROOT}/resources-to-copy-${TARGETNAME}.txt
> "$RESOURCES_TO_COPY"

I updated rsync, I did an upgrade for all packages for brew. I did other steps to clear the cache of the emulator, the derive data folder, etc. Finally, I made sure rsync, Terminal, watchman and Xcode have Full disk access authorisation.
Usually when I do a fresh install of React-Native with the package reinstalled, it works relatively well but not this time. I use the following command for macOS ARM chip "sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi && cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install" to create the pods.
Who's got some experience with this type of issues ?

I used step by step recreation of the installation of the project from blank and arrived at the conclusion that the issue was inside the iOS folder, I used xcdiff to compare xcodeproj to list all differences with a brand new one. Finally, I found that the issue comes from a recommandation of Xcode that I unfortunately applied. The solution to solve the problem was changing the option in Xcode :
Build Settings/Build Options/
User Script Sandboxing :
Yes to No

